# How can i get a single data from local api using react and redux?

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, react-redux

I am trying to create a ecommerce shop website and I am using redux for storing states of my project , for simple test at the beginning I created an local api in my backend folder , I have fetched my list of product datas for the homepage successfully but when I am trying to access the single product in single page it gives me 404 error from api status (product not found)!!the api address is definitely correct and i have tried to that address in postman directly and got the data by id but can't access to that url in front end...!

here is my api call actions >>

```
      import {
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_START,
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
  } from "ActionConsts";
  import axios from "axios";


export const getSingleProduct = (productId) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_START,
    payload: productId,
  });
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`api/products/${productId}`);
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload:
        err.response && err.response.data.message
          ? err.response.data.message
          : err.message,
    });
  }
};
```

this is my reducer >>

```
    export const productDetailReducer = (
      state = { product: {}, loading: true },
      action
    ) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case PRODUCT_DETAILS_START:
          return { loading: true };
    
        case PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
          return {
            loading: false,
            product: action.payload,
          };
    
        case PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL:
          return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
```

this is my store >>

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { productReducer, productDetailReducer } from "Reducers";

const inState = {};
const reducer = combineReducers({
  productList: productReducer,
  productDetails: productDetailReducer,
});
const composeEnhancers =
  (typeof window !== "undefined" &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) ||
  compose;

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  inState,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export default store;
```

and here is the single page for gating data >>

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { SingelAll } from "Components";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { getSingleProduct } from "Actions";

export const Single = (props) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productId = id;
  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
  const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getSingleProduct(productId));
  }, [dispatch, productId]);

  console.log(product);

  return (
    <>
      <SingelAll loading={loading} error={error} product={product} />
    </>
  );
};
```

This is the notfound error >>

[image: 1]

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You specify the api url relative to the current page url:

```
...
const { data } = await axios.get(`api/products/${productId}`);
...

// the api url will change depending on the url of the current page 
// http://localhost:3000 -> http://localhost:3000/api/products/${productId}
// http://localhost:3000/product -> http://localhost:3000/product/api/products/${productId}
// http://localhost:3000/about -> http://localhost:3000/about/api/products/${productId}
// ...etc
```

Just add a leading slash for the api address. It ensures the path is absolute to the root directory and not the current directory

```
...
const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${productId}`);
...
```